# How to set processwide variables in Activiti?

Tags: workflow, share, alfresco, activiti

I am trying to set process-wide variables, which are shown not only in the next task but also in workflow details view.

I tried: (*ServiceTask*)

```
execution.setVariable("san_value", "1000");
```

or: (*TaskListener*)

```
String myprocessinstanceid = delegateTask.getProcessInstanceId();
ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
RuntimeService myruntimeservice = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
myruntimeservice.setVariable(myprocessinstanceid, "san_value", delegateTask.getVariable("san_value"));
```

But with this code I am only able to pass variable from one task to another. But when I enter "Workflow Details" view, **all variables are empty!**

How can I set them?

PS. Do I really have to set every variable in every single task? Shouldn't it be automatic?

Comment: are you using activiti embedded in Alfresco?

Comment: What is your APS/ Alfresco & activiti (embedded) version ?

Comment: @AbbasKararawala Muralidharan Deenathayalan, I'm using Alfresco 6.1.2 Community Edition (Activiti enginee is embedded and I guess it is version 5.22)

Answer (score 0):

RuntimeService.setVariable takes execution ID as the first variable, not process instance ID.

So pass in the delegateTask.getExecutionId() instead.